# Sum of values in fields got by change function in form with Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have form as follows :

```
<input name="website_charges" id="website_charges" type="text" value="" /><br>
<input name="monthly_fixed_charges" id="monthly_fixed_charges" type="text" value="" />

<input name="members_registered" id="members_registered" type="text" value=""  /><br>
<input name="per_member" id="per_member" type="text" value="" /><br>
<input name="member_total_charges" id="member_total_charges" type="text" value="" /><br>

<input name="monthly_sessions" id="monthly_sessions" type="text" value="" /><br>
<input name="per_session" id="per_session" type="text" value="" /><br>
<input name="session_total_charges" id="session_total_charges" type="text" value="" /><br>

<input name="total_dues" id="total_dues" type="text" value="" /><br>
<input name="paid_amount" id="paid_amount" type="text" value="" /><br>
<input name="balance" id="balance" type="text" value="" /><br>
```

Out of These **#website_charges**, **#monthly_fixed_charges**, **#members_registered**, **#per_member**, **#monthly_sessions**, **#per_session** fields are manually entered.

currently my javascript code adding **#member_total_charges** and **#session_total_charges** dynamically.

But I am not getting How To *Sum* And *Add* These Two Dynamically added field values (i.e. **#member_total_charges** and **#session_total_charges**) + **#website_charges** + **#monthly_total_charges** in ***#total_dues*** field And Then Show Final Balance in **#balance** field after entering **#paid_amount** Fiield?

Current Javascript code is as follows :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#member_registered, #per_member').change(function(){
    var mem = parseInt($('#member_registered').val()) || 0;
    var permem = parseInt($('#per_member').val()) || 0;

    $('#member_total_charges').val(mem * permem);    
   });
   $('#monthly_sessions, #per_session').change(function(){
    var month = parseInt($('#monthly_sessions').val()) || 0;
    var perses= parseInt($('#per_session').val()) || 0;

    $('#session_total_charges').val(month * perses);    
});
});
</script>
```

**[JSFIDDLE Is Here****](http://jsfiddle.net/vaidyamanishjoshi/cx3j3ewb/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

To bind elements which generated dynamicly, use `.live()` function to binding events:

```
$("#member_total_charges, #session_total_charges").live("change", function () {
  //do sum work
});
```

Note that `change` event only triggers after the `<input>` lost focus, so if you want to run the sum function as soon as you type a char, use `keyup` event instead.

Comment: I am trying as following...But it is showing dynamiccally sumup of values in #member_total_charges and #session_total_charges only... code is

Comment: $("#member_total_charges, #session_total_charges").live("change",function(){
     var memtc = parseInt($('#member_total_charges').val()) || 0;
     var sestc = parseInt($('#session_total_charges').val()) || 0;
     
     
     $('#subtotal_dues').val(memtc + sestc);    
    });
    $("#subtotal, #subtotal_dues").live("change", function(){
     var memtca = parseInt($('#subtotal').val()) || 0;
     var sestca = parseInt($('#subtotal_dues').val()) || 0;
     
     
     $('#total_dues').val(memtca + sestca);    
    });
});

Comment: so you are saying the binding doesn't work, or the sum function doesn't work well?

Comment: No...Not Like That.... basically Total Dues = website_charges + monthly_fixed_charges + member_total_charges +session_total_charges.....THEN total_dues - amount_paid = balance

Comment: Thanx for your help. JSFiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/vaidyamanishjoshi/cx3j3ewb/1/

Comment: That is because your green field is set as `readonly`, which would never get/lost focus as well as trigger the function.You can bind all the typeing with `keyup`: http://jsfiddle.net/Bandon/cx3j3ewb/3/

Answer (score 0):

Try using this code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#member_registered, #per_member').on('input change',function(){
    var mem = parseInt($('#member_registered').val()) || 0;
    var permem = parseInt($('#per_member').val()) || 0;

    $('#member_total_charges').val(mem * permem);    
   });
   $('#monthly_sessions, #per_session').on('input change',function(){
    var month = parseInt($('#monthly_sessions').val()) || 0;
    var perses= parseInt($('#per_session').val()) || 0;

    $('#session_total_charges').val(month * perses);    
    });
    $('#member_total_charges, #session_total_charges').on('change',function(){
     var memtc = parseInt($('#member_total_charges').val()) || 0;
     var sestc = parseInt($('#session_total_charges').val()) || 0;

     $('#total_dues').val(memtc + sestc);    
    });
});
</script>
```

using the on() method will work better and you can use multiple arguments input, change, mouseover etc...
So basicly if you want to change a dynamically added values select theri id'and call .on() method with the string of parameters that you need and then your statement, like you did for your previous elements.
And if you have any troubles you can check [this](http://api.jquery.com/on/).
I hope this was helpfull

Comment: Thanks ...but unfortunatelly, it is showing only #member_total_charegs and #session_total_charges Only. But Not Showing #total_dues. Also #website_charges and #monthly_fixed_charges are not included in your solution...

Comment: @DrManishJoshi give me some time i will try to build a working solution for you

Comment: @DrManishJoshi  thanks for the JS fiddle i'll try to fixx it and get back to you, would be great if we could chat about it outside the coment section.

Comment: Good to see that you figured it out before me:)

Answer (score 0):

I Solved it as follows:

1) I removed all readonly attributes as suggested by @Bandon

2) Updated Code (By Editing code given by @Bandon jsfiddle) Is As Follows :

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#website_charges, #monthly_fixed_charges').on('input change', function () {
    var web = parseInt($('#website_charges').val()) || 0;
    var mfc = parseInt($('#monthly_fixed_charges').val()) || 0;
    $('#subtotal').val(web + mfc);
});

$('#member_registered, #per_member').on('input change', function () {
    var mem = parseInt($('#member_registered').val()) || 0;
    var permem = parseInt($('#per_member').val()) || 0;

    $('#member_total_charges').val(mem * permem);
});
$('#monthly_sessions, #per_session').on('input change', function () {
    var month = parseInt($('#monthly_sessions').val()) || 0;
    var perses = parseInt($('#per_session').val()) || 0;

    $('#session_total_charges').val(month * perses);
});
$("input").live("keyup focus blur", "#subtotal_dues, #total_dues, #balance", function () {        
    var memtc = parseInt($('#member_total_charges').val()) || 0;
    var sestc = parseInt($('#session_total_charges').val()) || 0;
    $('#subtotal_dues').val(memtc + sestc);
    var memtca = parseInt($('#subtotal').val()) || 0;
    var sestca = parseInt($('#subtotal_dues').val()) || 0;
    $('#total_dues').val(memtca + sestca);
    var td = parseInt($('#total_dues').val()) || 0;
    var paid = parseInt($('#paid_amount').val()) || 0;
    $('#balance').val(td - paid);
    });
});
</script>
```

**[UPDATED JSFIDDLE IS HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/vaidyamanishjoshi/fw7quo2a/2/)**

Thank to @Bandon